# Let G be a finite group that has elements of every orders from 1 - 12. What is the smallest possible value of |G|

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let G be a finite group that has elements of every orders from 1 through 12. What is the smallest possible value of |G|

I need your help

Comment: Do you know that if $g \in G$, then $|g| \mid |G|$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the order of every element divides the order of the group, $G$ must be at least the lowest common multiple of the numbers $1$ to $12$. This number turns out to be $m=2^3\cdot3^2\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11 = 27720$.

If you look at $\mathbb{Z}_m$, you can easily see that in fact it has elements of all orders from 1 to 12. So $27720$ is the answer.

Comment: I have question, How could you get  these 23⋅32⋅5⋅7⋅11

Comment: It is a way to calculate the lcm of numbers: These are the prime numbers from 1 to 12, raised to the power of their highest occurance: $8=2^3$, $9=3^2$, all other primes only appear at most once in a number from $1$ to $12$.

Answer (score 1):

By Lagrange, it would have to have order at least the LCM of the integers from 1-12. Can you think of a group of this order, and does it have elements of all of these orders?

Answer (score 0):

To add to previous answers and comments, note that the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_m$ has an element of order $n \iff n|m$.  Can  you prove this?  Would such a group be the smallest group?